# How to detect that instance passed to std::bind has destroyed

Tags: c++, std-function

I have a singleton that contains a list of `std::function` and periodically calls that.

```
class MySingleton
{
public:
    static MySingleton &instance()
    {
        static MySingleton inst;
        return inst;
    }

    void addFunc(const std::function<void(void)> &func)
    {
        m_list.push_back(func);
    }

protected:
    void periodicallyCalled()
    {
        for(auto f: m_list)
        {
            f();
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> m_list;
}
```

usage:

```
class Test
{
public:
    void test()
    {
        somenum ++;
    }
protected:
    int somenum = 0;
}


Test *inst1 = new Test;
auto f1 = std::bind(&Test::test, inst1, std::placeholders::_1);
MySingleton::instance().addFunc(f1);

Test *inst2 = new Test;
auto f2 = std::bind(&Test::test, inst2, std::placeholders::_1);
MySingleton::instance().addFunc(f2);
```

after a while I destroy one of objects:

```
delete inst1;
```

and `periodicallyCalled()` will crash since instance one of `std::function`s points on doesn't exist.

So  my question - is there some way to prevent that? How can I detect that instance was deleted and I can safety remove such `std::function` from the list?

Comment: What about using a weak pointer?

Answer (score 3):

> is there some way to prevent that?

Remove the function from the list **before** destroying the object that the function is using.

> How can I detect that instance was deleted and I can safety remove such std::function from the list?

You can’t.  At least, not the way you have written the code.  So, remove the function first.

If you really want to detect whether the object is alive, wrap the object in a `std::shared_ptr` and then store a `std::weak_ptr` to it along with the function that uses it.  Then you can query the `std::weak_ptr` before calling the function.  Or, store the `std::shared_ptr` instead, and query its refcount for > 1 before calling the function.

Comment: Sure, this is the solution that suggests itself. But what if the class is out of my control? Let's say I provide it as a library. In this case it will crash in case of improper use. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Ok, `std::weak_ptr` is interesting idea, I have to test that ...

Answer (score 0):

You use C++ contructors and destructors in what is commonly called the [RAII pattern](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)

```
class MySingleton
{
public:
    static MySingleton &instance()
    {
        static MySingleton inst;
        return inst;
    }

    int addFunc(const std::function<void(void)> &func)
    {
        int nKey = m_nKey++;
        m_mapfunc.emplace(nKey, func);
        return nKey;
    }

    void removeFunc(int nKey) {
        m_mapfunc.erase(nKey);
    }

protected:
    void periodicallyCalled()
    {
        for(auto pairnfn: m_mapfunc)
        {
            pairnfn.second();
        }
    }

private:
    int m_nKey = 0;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::function<void(void)>> m_mapfunc;
};

class Test
{
public:
    Test() : m_nKey(
      MySingleton::instance().addFunc(std::bind(&Test::test, this, std::placeholders::_1))
    ) 
    {}

    ~Test() {
      MySingleton::instance().removeFunc(m_nKey);
    }
    void test()
    {
        somenum ++;
    }
protected:
    int m_nKey;
    int somenum = 0;
}
```